# Join tables with names matching a pattern

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a query where I want to join all tables with names that match a specific pattern.

**Example**

I have 12 tables (one for each month) containing daily temperature values and I want to return temperatures across any range of dates (e.g. 1/26/2014-3/5/2014).

My tables are named with the pattern `temperature_m01`, `temperature_m02`, ..., `temperature_m12`.

I can simply join all tables together by writing out each join explicitly but I want a cleaner way to imply that I want to join all tables `temperature_m*`.

Once I know how to do this I figure I can add some additional constrains, such as only joining the tables for the months in the range I need, which might give slight improvements.

---

So far I am thinking that the best way to do this is use python to write the query for me, but this doesn't seem particularly clean either.

Comment: There's not a clean way as this is not a standard practice (separating  tables by an attribute like year).  You could build up a SQL string dynamically but there's not a SQL syntax to select multiple tables with a wildcard.

Comment: @DStanley - What about a View `UNION ALL`ing the tables as if using a partitioning scheme?

Answer (score 2):

This is normally an anti-pattern, you should rather have a single table with a field that indicates the month.

You can, however, create a view to combine your 12 tables and query that as if it were all of your tables together...

```
CREATE VIEW temperature_all AS (
    SELECT 01 AS month_id, * FROM temperature_m01
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 02 AS month_id, * FROM temperature_m02
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 03 AS month_id, * FROM temperature_m03
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 04 AS month_id, * FROM temperature_m04
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 05 AS month_id, * FROM temperature_m05
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 06 AS month_id, * FROM temperature_m06
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 07 AS month_id, * FROM temperature_m07
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 08 AS month_id, * FROM temperature_m08
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 09 AS month_id, * FROM temperature_m09
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 AS month_id, * FROM temperature_m10
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 AS month_id, * FROM temperature_m11
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 12 AS month_id, * FROM temperature_m12
);

SELECT * FROM temperature_all WHERE your_date_field BETWEEN '2014-01-26' AND '2014-03-05';
```

This is similar to how partitioning works.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is a bad data structure.  You should have all the data in a single table, with a column representing the month.

That said, Postgres offers a couple of things that can help.  One is to use a view (as Matt answers in another question).

Another is to use [inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-inherit.html).  So, you could create a parent table, say `temperature_m`, and do:

```
alter table temperature_m01 inherits temperature_m;
```

This then allows you to do:

```
select . . .
 from temperature_m*
```

However, for this to work, you'll have to put the common columns you want in `temperature_m` . . . and we are back to creating a single table for the data.  That is really the best approach.